# Mysql service failed to start after I remove all log file

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I delete all file in /var/log, however, when I restart mysql service, it failed to start now.
help!

Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service mysql restart

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the stop(8) and then start(8) utilities,
e.g. stop mysql ; start mysql. The restart(8) utility is also available.
start: Job failed to start

Comment: Hmmmm, binlog index could be the problem, but anything really... (1) what does your error log say (or error output with manual start) & (2) belongs on serverfault.com

Comment: Note to flaggers: Don't migrate crap. Close this question, don't migrate it, until it has necessary details added (like the actual error message).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try creating Directory Manually & Assign the Permission to Mysql.

```
Ex. mkdir /var/log/mysql 
Chown -R mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql
```

& Restart the mysql Service again it might be slove your problem.

Comment: Thanks,but it still can't start and apache2 service is also can't start.

Comment: ok can you copy & paste your mysql & apache error logs ---Last 20 lines only..so i might be try to solve your problem

Comment: There's nothing in /var/log/mysql

Comment: And apache2 is OK now after I creat apache2 folder

Comment: same with apache you create manual dir to mysql but dont forget to assign the permission to mysql otherwise it wont work check your /etc/my.cnf --Log parameter where mysql exatly saving the log...

Comment: Thank you. I have to reinstall mysql and it's OK now.

Comment: I had deleted log files using stacer application but the above command help me to restart the application

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your my.cnf is "world wide writable" ?
Check permissions.
It should be like 755...
NOT 777.

Answer (score 0):

try running mysqld using

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld
```

i have once come across this problem. i.e. my mysql says `Job can't start` .I don't know why but it started after

```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5
   /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

May be there is some bug on `service` routine.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-create the "log pool" yourself

```
mkdir /var/log/mysql
```

And give it full access

```
chmod -R 777 /var/log/mysql
```

Now restart your db server

```
service mysql start 
or
/usr/sbin/mysqld
```